# MVC validation for each item in List<string>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to validate each item at List of string with some RegExp.

```
[RegularExpression("@"^[a-zA-Z]+$"")]
public List<string> Titles{ get; set; }
```

But this attribute validate field at whole, not each item at list. I need to save client-side validation, too.

Comment: Sounds like you will be creating your first Custom Validator!

Comment: @John Hartsock, I try to understand, is there a way to solve my issue without creating custom validator.

Comment: There is not a current validator that will do what you want.  You will need to create one,